# aiohttp api error handler framework

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, exception, pytest-aiohttp

we have developed some of the aiohttp server side apis and from that api we am calling one of the python class, where i have done all business logic.

now we want to create a error handling framework for all apis, please give some ideas to implement that framework and i need to do request parameters validations as well, should i consolidate and send back all error at one time or just check one parameter send back the error message to caller.

api look like this:

```
 async def new_user(request):
try:
    # happy path where name is set
    user = request.query['name']
    # Process our new user
    print("Creating new user with name: " , user)

    response_obj = { 'status' : 'success' }
    # return a success json response with status code 200 i.e. 'OK'
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj), status=200)
except Exception as e:
    # Bad path where name is not set
    response_obj = { 'status' : 'failed', 'reason': str(e), 'code' : 400 }
    # return failed with a status code of 500 i.e. 'Server Error'
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj), status=400)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `aio-http` try to create `aiohttp.web.middleware`.

https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#middlewares